# Differentiation of $f(x)=2x(2+3x^2)^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question:

> Differentiate $f(x)=2x(2+3x^2)^3$.

How do I approach this problem? Do I only have to use the product rule...? I have the answer but I don't know how to get there.

Here is my attempt to this problem:

$$\frac{df}{dx}=(2)(2+3x^2)^3 + (2x)(6x)(3)(2+3x^2)^2 = \\ =(2+3x^2)^2 [(2)(2+3x^2) + (2x)(6x)(3)] = \\ = (2+3x^2)^2 [(4+6x^2) + 36x^2] = \\ = (2+3x^2)^2 (42x^2+4)$$

Answer (score 1):

You get the right answer:

$$(2+3x^2)^2 (42x^2+4)=(2+3x^2)^2 \cdot 2 \cdot (21x^2+2)$$

Comment: omg how did i miss that ... it was driving me nuts .. thanks :)